# Use of "not primarily" in "Saw creating the 7 habits not primarily...."

Tags: adverbs

> he saw creating the 7 Habits  not primarily as a means of his own success.

In the above mentioned sentence I want to know whether the usage of "not primarily " is correct or not.  Please provide me with a proper explanation.   Does "not primarily" come before the gerund or after the object of the gerund?[image]

Comment: "Not probably" is very awkward and non-fluent here.  But as cobaltduck says, it's hard to tell you how to correct it if you don't tell us what you want to say.

Comment: Also, the picture you posted says "not **primarily**", not "not *probably*".

Comment: You have used the correct word 'primarily' in the quote in the title, but misread it as 'probably' everywhere else. Change that and your question will make more sense. :)

Comment: Consider: *He saw purchasing the restaurant not primarily as a way to offer delicious food to the neighborhood but as a way to launder money.*  The main or primary purpose was to launder money. Offering delicious food was *secondary* in its importance.  And it is **a means *to* {an end}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He saw creating the 7 Habits **not** primarily as a means to his own success, **but as** an act of service. [The sentence is referring to the book *The Seven Habits of Highly Effective People*]

In English, you can construct a sentence containing the reason for something by using the the word **as** in a phrase to mean having the purpose or function of:

- He did that **as a favor to his brother**.

That utterance can be put in the negative like this:

- He did that **not as a favor to his brother but as a favor to his father**.

It could also be **put in the negative** like this, in a shorter form:

- He **didn't do that as a favor** to this brother but to his father.

**As a means to his own success** is an example of a noun phrase using ***as*** to mean for the purpose of.

Also, in the sentence above, the noun phrase "as a means to his own success" is preceded by: to **see creating** the 7 Habits is standard English.

transitive verb + gerund noun = He **sees playing tennis** as a type of endurance sport. They **understand being politically involved** as a vital necessity.

The verb see here means: to understand.
Transitive verbs may be followed by gerund nouns.

Comment: Thank you so much but can we use primarily after negation? And one more thing this word primarily is modifying creating or saw? Please clear this doubt. Thank you

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd be happy to clear **up** any doubt. To see creating x primarily as: answers the question: how does he see creating x? So, for me, it goes with see (saw). :)

Comment: Thank you once again .one more doubt can we us adverb which is "not" before the word " primarily"  please give full explanation

Comment: To not primarily see something as x.